# pyenv shell errors after uninstalling pyenv

Tags: python, shell, homebrew, zsh, pyenv

I've recently been diagnosing why my pyenv installation is giving me errors in the shell. After trying everything I could find, I thought I would remove it from my system. However, after uninstalling, I am still seeing `pyenv shell` when loading a new terminal and `zsh: command not found: pyenv`

Steps I took:

`rm -rf $(pyenv root)`

`brew uninstall pyenv`

I have checked my `.zshrc`,`.zprofile`, `.zlogin` and there are no references to pyenv in any of them

I am using homebrew on Mac with oh-my-zsh(no pyenv plugin)

At a loss for where to look to remove this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a VSCode thing. Opening a new terminal outside of VSCode didn't give the errors. It's due to the Python extension that was installed trying to activate an environment:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
```

Comment: So you had to remove this setting? I am facing the same problem, but don't have this setting.

Comment: Correct, go to your Settings, type "python.terminal.activateEnvironment" in the search and deactivate the setting.